# Floating point inaccuracy during e calculation with numerical methods

Tags: java, variables, double, precision

So i was calculating e(third row in picture) with numerical methods.

[image]

I was increasing the number of elements i used every iteration. And when i executed the program, floating point variable behaved in a way i didn't understand. Here is the program and the result.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Test {

       public static void main(String[] args) {

          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

          int factorial = 1;
          int counter = 0;
          int iterationNumber;
          double total = 0;
          int tempCounter;

          System.out.print("Enter iteration number: ");
          iterationNumber = input.nextInt();

          while (counter <= iterationNumber) {

             tempCounter = counter;

             while ((tempCounter - 1) > 0) {
                factorial *= tempCounter;
                tempCounter--;
             }

             total += ((double)1 / factorial);
             System.out.println(total);

             factorial = 1;
             counter ++;
          }
       }
    }
```

[image]

So my question is why does the value of e starts to decrease after a while instead of increasing? I want to learn how floating point variable behaves during this program and the logic behind it.

Another question is why does it start to say infinity?

Comment: Because when 1/(n!) gets too small you have a flowting point overflow and so the value gets negative and in the sum your result gets smaller.

Comment: Try using `BigDecimal` for those calculations. You'll still have to define a precision and rounding mode but you still can get far better precision and higher numerical range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`n!` quickly exceeds [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) and overflows to a negative number. You are then adding a negative number to your total --- thus the decrease.

You can use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for your calcualtions. It is slower, but will do the job.